# управление зависимостями package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

Я установил несколько пакетов, забыв прописать для них флаги --save. Кроме этого удалил пару ненужных пакетов просто удалив их папки. В файл package.json зависимости не поменялись.Есть ли простой или автоматический способ или команда обновить зависимости в package.json, чтобы не заморачиваться вручную?

Answer (score 1):

Неиспользуемые зависимости можно удалить из package.json с помощью вот такого модуля:

```
npm install cleanup-dependencies
```

В нужной папке вызываете

```
clean-deps
```